# MySQL weighted average

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a SQL Database on PHPMyAdmin and I'm trying to write queries for it.

One of the queries I want to write is: Find the average of a column all containing datetimes and display that average. Problem I have is that one item was brought twice at the same time. The table name is Orders. For example:

[image: here is a picture of the data]

How would I write this SQL query?

The end result I want a datetime which is the average of all the datetimes above. Remembering the bottom datatime figure has to be calculated twice into the average.

Thanks!

Comment: I removed the MySQL and SQL Server tags.  Please add the database tag of the specific database you are using.  That is important information for such a question.

Comment: How do I find out what database I am using? :S I just created a database in PHPMyAdmin..

Comment: If it's phpmyadmin, you'll most likely be using MySQL.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to all this! :)

Comment: You mean you want a weighted average? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192719/how-do-i-get-a-proper-weighted-average-date-in-sql

Comment: @Pleun So something like this?    WITH    Orders (DateTimeStart, Quantity) AS
        (
        SELECT  CAST(Orders.DateTimeStart AS DATETIME), 1.0
        UNION ALL
        )
SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME, SUM(CONVERT(FLOAT, DateTimeStart) * Quantity) / SUM(Quantity))
FROM    Orders

Comment: @TomPitts: WITH is for MSSQL, you cannot use it on MySQL. What is your expected result? What do you want to see at the end? Can you put it on your question?

Comment: What result would you expect with `2015-10-01 00:00:00, 2015-10-01 00:00:00 and 2015-10-01 01:00:00`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, this was a tough one. But it looks like I got it working. I've tried several things, but was unable to use the mysql avg function after all:

```sql
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(SUM(Quantity * UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DateTimeStart)) / SUM(Quantity)) AS `avg-time` FROM orders;
```

How did I get to this query?

1. I assume your table is called 'orders'.
2. To calculate with dates it is preferred to convert the dates first to [unix timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). I use the [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) mysql function to do this.
3. I multiply each datetimestart (as unix timestamps) with its quantity.
4. I calculate the sum of the those.
5. I divide this by the total sum of quantities
6. We could be done now. But I guess you'd like to have a readable form again (me too actually), so to convert the average unix timestamp back to a readable date I use [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime).

Comment: Is that the whole query? Just stuck it in my sql query and errors :/

Comment: Yes, that's the whole query. What errors are you getting?

Comment: Ok, I will admit I'm an idiot, I didn't copy the whole code! :') Can you also check out my question I did a couple of minutes ago regarding another query? Thanks.

Comment: Doing something stupid, and then search for the cause for hours? Happens to everyone :P
Well, I saw there are already answers there. You need to move the where part to the end of the query.